# Non linear model fit with trigonometric model

Tags: fitting, trigonometry

I tried to fit the curve of the dataset. I used 'Nonlinearmodelfit' function to get the specific fitted equation. Yes, I can get the result, but I am wondering there is a way to improve the result.

This is the dataset, basically {Angle, Intensity}

```
data={{0.,4852.},{0.0872665,3128.},{0.174533,2686.},{0.261799,6450.},{0.349066,15532.},{0.436332,28730.},{0.523599,42838.},{0.610865,52648.},{0.698132,51744.},{0.785398,66190.},{0.872665,71260.},{0.959931,73682.},{1.0472,67820.},{1.13446,53786.},{1.22173,36626.},{1.309,26750.},{1.39626,28354.},{1.48353,26258.},{1.5708,19888.},{1.65806,19844.},{1.74533,16350.},{1.8326,15732.},{1.91986,12062.},{2.00713,9996.},{2.0944,15350.},{2.18166,17160.},{2.26893,21986.},{2.35619,19248.},{2.44346,22100.},{2.53073,20096.},{2.61799,16962.},{2.70526,15510.},{2.79253,14280.},{2.87979,11278.},{2.96706,7664.},{3.05433,5452.},{3.14159,3114.},{3.22886,1712.},{3.31613,1860.},{3.40339,3510.},{3.49066,7498.},{3.57792,19636.},{3.66519,38690.},{3.75246,56766.},{3.83972,68802.},{3.92699,64136.},{4.01426,74730.},{4.10152,83330.},{4.18879,63400.},{4.27606,48962.},{4.36332,35622.},{4.45059,22414.},{4.53786,15704.},{4.62512,11696.},{4.71239,10184.},{4.79966,9836.},{4.88692,11946.},{4.97419,11496.},{5.06145,13668.},{5.14872,18054.},{5.23599,31018.},{5.32325,37838.},{5.41052,47124.},{5.49779,55154.},{5.58505,46564.},{5.67232,34936.},{5.75959,27916.},{5.84685,22714.},{5.93412,15792.},{6.02139,12696.},{6.10865,8584.},{6.19592,8166.}}
```

And, These below are the model and parameters that I used.

```
Model= a + b*Cos[x] + c*Cos[2x] + d*Cos[3x] + e*Cos[4x] + f*Cos[5x] + g*Cos[6x] + h*Sin[x] + i*Sin[2x] + j*Sin[3x] + k*Sin[4x] + l*Sin[5x] + m*Sin[6x]
coeff = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m};
nlm = Normal[NonlinearModelFit[data, model , coeff , x, MaxIterations -> 1000]];
```

Thank you

Comment: Another approach would be to use a Fourier transform.

Comment: bill's approach is the most efficient if your points are equispaced; otherwise, you would really need to do full least squares.

Comment: I think this is a linear model (linear in the unknown coefficients)

Answer (score 5):

Mikado's comment to the original question is on the money: this is a linear model; not a non-linear one. This makes the fit much easier and faster with `LinearModelFit`, since you don't have to worry about local minima. With linear models you normally don't have to fudge around nearly as much:

```
basisFun = {
   1, Cos[x], Cos[2 x], Cos[3 x], Cos[4 x], Cos[5 x],
   Cos[6 x], Sin[x], Sin[2 x], Sin[3 x], Sin[4 x], Sin[5 x], Sin[6 x]
};
fit = LinearModelFit[data, basisFun, x];
Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[fit[x], {x, 0, 2 π}]]
```

> [image]

## Edit

Bonus content:

```
fourrierFit[data_, n_Integer, k : _?NumericQ : 1] := LinearModelFit[
   data,
   Flatten[{Sin[# k \[FormalX]], Cos[# k \[FormalX]]} & /@ Range[n]],
   \[FormalX]
];
Manipulate[
 Show[ListPlot[data],
  Plot[
   Evaluate @ Map[
     Legended[fourrierFit[data, #, k]["BestFit"], #] &,
     Range[6]
     ],
   {\[FormalX], 0, 2 π}
   ]
 ],
 {{k, 1}, 0.1, 5}
]
```

If you want nice, Bayesian, error bars take a look at my [ResourceFunction](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/BayesianLinearRegression):

```
k = 1;
n = 6
basisFuns = Flatten[{Sin[# k \[FormalX]], Cos[# k \[FormalX]]} & /@ Range[n]];
fit = ResourceFunction["BayesianLinearRegression"][data, basisFuns, \[FormalX]];
Show[
 ListPlot[data],
 Plot[
  Evaluate @ InverseCDF[fit["Posterior", "PredictiveDistribution"], {0.95, 0.5, 0.05}],
  {\[FormalX], 0, 2 π},
  Filling -> {1 -> {2}, 3 -> {2}},
  PlotLegends -> Table[Quantity[i, "Percent"], {i, {95, 50, 5}}]
  ],
 Plot[
  Evaluate @ InverseCDF[fit["Posterior", "UnderlyingValueDistribution"], {0.95, 0.5, 0.05}],
  {\[FormalX], 0, 2 π},
  Filling -> {1 -> {2}, 3 -> {2}},
  PlotStyle -> Dashed
 ]
]
```

> [image]

Comment: +1 *Mathematica* needs more Bayesian exposure.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to stick with pairs of sines and cosines, then using AICc is a reasonable approach to determine an appropriate number of pairs.

Rewriting your code to allow for any number of pairs of sines and cosines:

```
data = {{0., 4852.}, {0.0872665, 3128.}, {0.174533, 2686.}, {0.261799, 6450.}, {0.349066, 15532.}, {0.436332, 28730.}, {0.523599, 42838.}, {0.610865, 52648.}, {0.698132, 51744.}, {0.785398, 66190.}, {0.872665, 71260.}, {0.959931, 73682.}, {1.0472, 67820.}, {1.13446, 53786.}, {1.22173, 36626.}, {1.309, 26750.}, {1.39626, 28354.}, {1.48353, 26258.}, {1.5708, 19888.}, {1.65806, 19844.}, {1.74533, 16350.}, {1.8326, 15732.}, {1.91986, 12062.}, {2.00713, 9996.}, {2.0944, 15350.}, {2.18166, 17160.}, {2.26893, 21986.}, {2.35619, 19248.}, {2.44346, 22100.}, {2.53073, 20096.}, {2.61799, 16962.}, {2.70526, 15510.}, {2.79253, 14280.}, {2.87979, 11278.}, {2.96706, 7664.}, {3.05433, 5452.}, {3.14159, 3114.}, {3.22886, 1712.}, {3.31613, 1860.}, {3.40339, 3510.}, {3.49066, 7498.}, {3.57792, 19636.}, {3.66519, 38690.}, {3.75246, 56766.}, {3.83972, 68802.}, {3.92699, 64136.}, {4.01426, 74730.}, {4.10152, 83330.}, {4.18879, 63400.}, {4.27606, 48962.}, {4.36332, 35622.}, {4.45059, 22414.}, {4.53786, 15704.}, {4.62512, 11696.}, {4.71239, 10184.}, {4.79966, 9836.}, {4.88692, 11946.}, {4.97419, 11496.}, {5.06145, 13668.}, {5.14872, 18054.}, {5.23599, 31018.}, {5.32325, 37838.}, {5.41052, 47124.}, {5.49779, 55154.}, {5.58505, 46564.}, {5.67232, 34936.}, {5.75959, 27916.}, {5.84685, 22714.}, {5.93412, 15792.}, {6.02139, 12696.}, {6.10865, 8584.}, {6.19592, 8166.}};

n = 6;
model = cs0 + Sum[c[i] Cos[i x] + s[i] Sin[i x], {i, n}];
coeff = Flatten[{cs0, Table[{c[i], s[i]}, {i, n}]}];
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, model, coeff, x]
Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[nlm[x], {x, 0, 2 π}]]
```

[image: Data and initial fit]

I assume this is the fit you found.

We can loop through and find the number of pairs with the smallest AICc value.

```
nmax = 25;
aicc = ConstantArray[{0, 0}, nmax];
Do[
 model = cs0 + Sum[c[i] Cos[i x] + s[i] Sin[i x], {i, n}];
 coeff = Flatten[{cs0, Table[{c[i], s[i]}, {i, n}]}];
 aicc[[n]] = {n, NonlinearModelFit[data, model, coeff, x]["AICc"]},
 {n, nmax}]

ListPlot[aicc, Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 16] &) /@ {"Number of sine and cosine pairs", 
  "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(AIC\), \(c\)]\)"}]
```

[image: Number of pairs of sines and cosines vs AICc]

So we see that n = 10 gives the lowest AICc value so we should not have any more than 10 pairs of sines and cosines.  That fit is as follows:

```
n = 10;
model = cs0 + Sum[c[i] Cos[i x] + s[i] Sin[i x], {i, n}];
coeff = Flatten[{cs0, Table[{c[i], s[i]}, {i, n}]}];
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, model, coeff, x];
Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[nlm[x], {x, 0, 2 π}]]
```

[image: Better fit]

Answer (score 1):

You can do Fourier analysis and decide, which Sin and Cos frequences over a choosen threshold you want to take into account and see the effect on fit. (Thanks to the ideas from other contributors!)

```
fou = Fourier[data[[All, 2]]];
tabc = Table[Cos[i x], {i, 1, Round[Length[data]/2]}];
tabs = Table[Sin[i x], {i, 1, Round[Length[data]/2]}];    
Manipulate[
 lp1 = {refou = Re[Rest@fou] /. (x_ /; Abs[x] < th) -> {}, 
 imfou = Im[Rest@fou] /. (x_ /; Abs[x] < th) -> {}}; 
 rc := refou /. (x_?NumericQ -> (x/x));
 rs := imfou /. (x_?NumericQ -> (x/x));
 cfun := DeleteCases[tabc rc[[1 ;; Round[Length[data]/2]]], {}];
 sfun := DeleteCases[tabs rs[[1 ;; Round[Length[data]/2]]], {}];
 basisFun = Join[{1}, cfun, sfun];
 fit = LinearModelFit[data, basisFun, x];
 {ListPlot[lp1, ImageSize -> 300, Filling -> Axis, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, Round[Length[data]/2]}, All}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}], 
  Plot[fit[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Epilog -> {Red, Point@data}, 
   ImageSize -> 300, 
   PlotRange -> {0, 1.1 Max[data[[All, 2]]]}]}, {{th, 10000}, 1000, 
  20000, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]